# c# append text to a rich text box from a thread using a delegate

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, richtextbox

I would like to have my TcpListen thread update a rich text box in Form1 using a delegate.  The TcpListen thread is working and communicating via console.  However, I can't get the rich text box in Form1 to append the text.

```
public class MyTcpListener
{
    public void Server()
    {
        // Some code that produces a string named data
        SendText(data)
    }

    public delegate void TextDelegate(string message);

    public void SendText(string message)
    {
        //Not sure how to send the string to Form1 without removing void and using return string?
    }

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyTcpListener listen = new MyTcpListener();
        tserv = new Thread(listen.Server);
        //tserv.IsBackground = true;
        tserv.Start();

        //Where would I call the DisplayText method?
    }
    public void DisplayText(string message)
    {
        if (richTextBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            richTextBox1.Invoke(new MyTcpListener.CallBackDelegate(DisplayText),
            new object[] { message });

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now.  The problem was that I was creating a new instance of Form1 in the MyTcpListener class (thread) instead of referencing the original Form1.  Thanks!

```
public class MyTcpListener
    {
        private Form1 form1;

        public MyTcpListener(Form1 form1)
        {
        this.form1 = form1;
        }

public partial class Form1 : Form
    { // Some code ...

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Start the thread ....
        //Originally I never instantiated an instance of MyTcpListener class
        MyTcpListener mytcplistener = new MyTcpListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put this in your Form1 class

```
public void AppendTextBox(string value)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action<string>(AppendTextBox), new object[] {value});
        return;
    }
    richTextBox1.AppendText(value);
}
```

And then pass the instance of Form1 to the TCPListener constructor, and when it needs to update the Form, call the AppendTextBox method of the form instance.

Comment: Hi Zach, thanks for the method above.  Is it possibleI am getting into trouble in MyTcpListener class (thread started in Form1_Load) because I am creating another instance of Form1 (Form1 form1 = new Form1();) that has no relation to the original instance?